# Extract lines from file with certain words using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file where each line has the following format:

```
1yjo    ASN 1   A   GLN 3   B   8.85
```

I have to extract each line where the second token is equal to `PHE` **and** the fifth token is equal to `LEU` **or** vice versa. For example:

```
2beg    LEU 17  A   VAL 18  C   8.76
2beg    LEU 17  A   PHE 19  A   7.2
2beg    PHE 19  A   ALA 21  B   8.88
2beg    PHE 19  D   LEU 34  E   13.28
```

If this was the input file, I would have to extract the second and the fourth line. It would be good to extract them to a separate file.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
@echo off
set inputfile=a.dat
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" %%a in (%inputfile%) do (
if %%b == "LEU" and %%e == "PHE" do (
@echo %%b %%e
)
)
```

...but it just copies the entire input file, i.e. the IF condition didn't have any effect...

Edit: I have also tried:

```
...
if %%b == "LEU" (
if %%e == "PHE" (
@echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h
)
)
...
```

...and it doesn't copy anything.

I'm also not so sure if I can use "and" and "or" operators, or I have to do it with multiple nested if's...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found a solution:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" %%a in (%1) do (
    if "%%b" == "%2" (
        if "%%e" == "%3" (
            @echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h >> output.txt
        )
    )
    if "%%b" == "%3" (
        if "%%e" == "%2" (
            @echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h >> output.txt
        )
    )
)
```

I have also used the input parameters for the input file name (%1) and the two strings (%2 and %3) and it works like a charm :)

Comment: This will not preserve the original spacing of the tokens. It wouldn't be hard to fix, but there are much simpler and faster ways than a FOR /F.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the pertinent lines, I would just use a basic pipe.

Like this in a cmd window:

```dos
Find " LEU "<"a.dat"|Find " PHE ">Output.txt
```

…or this from a batch file:

```dos
@Find " LEU "<"a.dat"|Find " PHE ">Output.txt
```

**[Edit /]**

As an update based upon the comments below, here is my idea using `findstr` in a batch file:

```dos
@FindStr/RC:"\<LEU .* PHE\>" /C:"\<PHE .* LEU\>" a.dat>Output.txt
```

Comment: +1, At first I thought this would be not restrictive enough. But then I realized it is highly unlikely that PHE or LEU could appear anywhere other than the 2nd and/or 5th tokens. But I prefer to use a single FINDSTR instead of multiple FIND

Comment: I had originally intended using findstr, _(similar to that which you have posted)_, but due to the common habit of OP's changing the parameters after having received a solution I decided to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can very efficiently (quickly) get your answer with a single FINDSTR regular expression search, though the search is awkward due to the crippled regular expression capabilities of FINDSTR. I'm assuming those are always spaces between the tokens, and not tabs. I used line continuation to make the command easier to read.

```
findstr /r /c:"^[^ ][^ ]*  *PHE  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *LEU "^
           /c:"^[^ ][^ ]*  *LEU  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *PHE " input.txt >output.txt
```

If you can rely on the fact that LEU and PHE never appear anywhere other than the 2nd and/or 5th tokens, then you can greatly simplify the search as:

```
findstr "PHE.*LEU LEU.*PHE" input.txt >output.txt
```

The precise search is much simpler with a proper regular expression tool. You could use powershell, or JScript for a native scripting regular expression solution. Or you could download a Windows version of grep, or ...

Since I already have it, I would use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged help.

```
jrepl "^\S+\s+(PHE|LEU)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(?!\1)(PHE|LEU)\s" "" /k 0 /f input.txt /o output.txt
```

In case you are not familiar with regular expressions:

- `^` marks the beginning of a line
- `\S+` matches one or more non-white space characters (any arbitrary token)
- `\s+` represents one or more white space characters (token delimiters)
- `(PHE|LEU)` matches PHE or LEU, and captures the match
- `(?!\1)` is a negative look-ahead that fails if the next string matches the previously captured match. (don't want to match PHE-PHE, or LEU-LEU)

Normally JREPL is used to find/replace strings. The `/k 0` option instructs JREPL to ignore the replace argument and simply printout all lines that match the search string.

The same regular expression could be used with most any proper regular expression tool.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same vtomic85's solution, but in a simpler and faster way. This version also preserve the original spacing.

```
@echo off
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
   for /F "tokens=2,5" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      if "%%b%%c" equ "%2%3" echo %%a
      if "%%b%%c" equ "%3%2" echo %%a
   )
)) > output.txt
```